# Reconstructing a sine wave using square waves and Möbius inversion: L² convergence?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

Let $s$ be the (“square wave”) $1$-periodic real function such that $s(x) = 1$ if $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$ and $s(x) = -1$ if $\frac{1}{2}<x<1$ (and maybe $s(0)=s(\frac{1}{2})=0$ for the sake of definitiveness, but I'll only be using $s$ a.e.).  In $L^2(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$, we have
$$
s(x) = \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(2(2m+1)\pi x)}{2m+1}
\tag{*}
$$
by a straightforward computation of its Fourier coefficients.  Now the Fourier coefficients in question are multiplicative, so I'd like to use the [Möbius inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) to reconstruct the sine wave using the square waves $s(kx)$, namely, I would *like to state*:
$$
\frac{4}{\pi} \sin(2\pi x) = \sum_{m=0}^{+\infty} \frac{\mu(2m+1)\,s((2m+1)x)}{2m+1}
\tag{†}
$$
where $\mu$ is the Möbius function.  Unless I am mistaken, (†) is clear if we just demand *weak* $L^2$ convergence of the RHS.  But I don't know how to say more.  Specifically:

> **Main question:** Is there (norm) $L^2$ convergence in (†)?

**Bonus points:** What can be said about convergence almost everywhere?  For even more credits, what can be said about convergence for a particular $x$ (maybe every $x\not\in\mathbb{Q}$)?  For super extra credits, discuss *uniform* convergence (I know the Gibbs phenomenon prevents uniform convergence in (*), but I don't see why this would forbid it in (†)).

Here is a graph of the partial sum for $m\leq 12$ of the RHS of (†):

[image: Sine wave represented using 12 square waves]

**Remarks:**

- Graphs, as well as a rendering as a sound wave (which is interesting, if not very pleasant to listen to) of the first few partial sums of the RHS of (†) are given in [this Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/gro_tsen/status/1225428841805631491).
- Lest anyone make the same mistake I made when thinking about this problem at first, the $s(kx)$ *are not* orthogonal in $L^2(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$.  (In fact, applying Gram-Schmidt to the $s(kx)$ produces a rather unexpected sequence of functions: [see here](https://twitter.com/gro_tsen/status/1228828262777925633) for some graphs.)
- I have a feeling this might be related to the question (which has independent interest) of finding an upper bound on $\sum_{k|n,\;k\leq B\;}\mu(k)$ as a function of $n$ and independently of $B$.  Maybe I should ask this as a separate question?
- The fact that the value at $0^+$ of the RHS of (†) converges to $0$ is equivalent to the prime number theorem, so the extra credits probably depend on some number theory, but I don't know what to think about mere $L^2$ convergence.

Comment: The RHS converges for every x, given that $\sum_{m=0}^M {\mu(2m+1) s((2m+1)x)}=o(M)$ for fixed x. The $o(M)$ result can be found in the footnote on p.3 of the paper [Quadratic Uniformity of the Mobius Function](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606087), namely, "qualitative versions of these results
... hold for rougher classes such as the continuous class $C^0$, or even piecewise continuous classes, by standard limiting arguments."